# How Do I Customise The Handsontable Pagination Footer?

Tags: javascript, pagination, handsontable

The Handsontable pagination example uses a very simple pagination technique of styling 6  tags.
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.19.0/demo-pagination.html

How can make it look more complete like the ng-grid/ui-grid pagination footer that has left/right arrows, number of rows per page in a selector etc?
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/314_external_pagination

Comment: This plugin is still very minimalist so the closest you'd be able to do is implement it yourself. It's not terribly hard to do so. Simply create a div for the footer, and have click events on the page numbers fetch the different data objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Zekes comment, I have added a div below the table and styled it using this simple control
http://www.pontikis.net/labs/bs_pagination/demo/